# Make a Custom loss function in Keras in detail

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I try to make a custom loss function in Keras.

I want to make this loss function

[image: loss function]

The dimension of output is 80. Batch size is 5000.

So I build this loss function below. But this doesn't work.

```
def normalize_activation(y_true, y_pred):
    nb_divide = K.reshape(K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(y_pred), axis=1)),(5000, 1))
    nb_divide=numpy.tile(nb_divide,80)
    predicted=numpy.divide(y_pred,nb_divide)
    return K.sum(K.square(y_true-predicted))
```

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

This error occurs. I think that the shape of y_true, y_pred is (5000,80).

where should I fix it??

Comment: It would be equivalent to use `losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, K.l2_normalize(y_pred, axis=-1))`.

Comment: Or you can add a `Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x, axis=-1))` layer at the end of your model, and use `loss='mse'`.

Comment: @Yu-Yang Thanks a lot! When use lambda, weight in last link should be 1. I can't make it. so I'm using your first solution. thank you. but I wonder meaning of axis=-1. I know axis=0, axis=1.

Comment: `axis=-1` is just “the last axis”, in this case it’ll be equivalent to `axis=1` so you can use either one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loss functions should avoid all kinds of operations that are not from [keras backend](https://keras.io/backend/). The values are tensors and you must keep them like tensors.

And you don't need to reshape things unless you actually want them to behave in a specific way.

If you have shapes (5000,80) and (5000,1), you can make operations with them without needing `K.repeat_elements()` (the equivalent to numpy.tile).

So, supposing that 5000 is the batch size (number of samples) and 80 is the only actual dimension belonging to a sample:

```
def normalize_loss(yTrue,yPred):
    nb_divide = K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(yPred),axis=1,keepdims=True)) 
        #keepdims=True keeps the shape like (5000,1)
        #this is not summing the entire batch, but only a single sample, is that correct?

    predicted = yPred/nb_divide
    return K.sum(K.square(yTrue-predicted))
```

---

Some observations:

- (I'm not a loss function expert here) You're dividing only the predicted part, but not the true part. Wouldn't that create big differences between both values and result in a misguiding loss function? (Again, I'm not the expert here)
- Usually people use `K.mean()` at the end of the loss function, but I see you used `K.sum()`. This is not a problem and doesn't prevent training from working. But you may like to visualize this same loss function for data with different sizes, and be able to compare them size-independently.